# Liberando memória com PHP usando __destruct

Tags: php, memória

É necessário usar o método `__destruct` e definir as variáveis da classe com `null` com objetivo de liberar memória de modo mais eficiente?

Por exemplo:

```
class Teste {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        // ...    
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->foo = null;   
        $this->bar = null;   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O __destruct é chamado automáticamente ao final do script como dito na própria [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php) `Destrutores são chamados durante o encerramento do script tendo os cabeçalhos HTTP enviados.`

E um adendo: atribuir `null` a uma variavel ainda consome memória pois ainda existe a referencia a propriedade que tem valor `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Creio que não, afinal o `__destruct` será chamado automaticamente quando as todas as referências são liberadas, ou quando o script termina.

Além disso, se você setar como `null` não faz liberar memória, por si só, ele só marca como um candidato para a coleta de lixo, que é exatamente o que o `_destruct` faz.